# Spark application behind a NAT using YARN cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In client deploy mode a Spark driver needs to be able to receive incoming TCP connections from Spark executors.  However, if the Spark driver is behind a NAT, it cannot receive incoming connections.  Will running the Spark driver in YARN cluster deploy mode overcome this limitation of being behind a NAT, because the Spark driver is then apparently executed on the Spark master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will running the Spark driver in YARN cluster deploy mode overcome this limitation of being behind a NAT, because the Spark driver is then apparently executed on the Spark master?

Yes, it will. Another possible approach is to configure:

- `spark.driver.port`
- `spark.driver.bindAddress`

and create SSH tunnel to one of the nodes.

Comment: Hi @user8371915 - Please could you elaborate? I am trying this approach with limited success on Spark 2.2.0

Comment: @user1158559 Overall you have to ensure full connectivity between all nodes in the cluster (master or its equivalent, workers, driver, executors). How you'll achieve these is up to you (you can find different solutions depending on the cluster configuration).